# conflicting versions in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

I installed Isabelle 2013-2 onto a Windows machine that already had a 2012 version.

Trying to read Lambda.thy from the Nominal Isabelle distribution (already discussed this on its mailing list) I get

```
Outer syntax error: command expected,
but identifier atom_decl was found
```

at

```
theory Lambda
imports
  "../Nominal2"
begin

atom_decl name
```

Could a version conflict cause this? How can I fix it then?

Does Isabelle store a state in some files or in the registry?

Comment: Do you use Isabelle/jEdit or Isabelle/ProofGeneral? How did you start the interface? I'm a linux-user myself, but I guess the following is the same on windows (since Isabelle makes use of cygwin): user relevant data is stored in $HOME/.isabelle/<Isabelle-versio>, which makes sure that different versions do not interfere (since they are "living" in different directories.

Comment: @chris, I use the jEdit version. Indeed there were separate version-named directories under cygwin's $HOME/.isabelle.

I started it by clicking on the Isabelle icon deployed on my desktop. 

Is this atom_decl defined after the 2012 release?

Comment: Could you give more details? From where exactly did you obtain the Nominal Isabelle distribution and how did you "install" it as well as Isabelle2013-2. Moreover, what is written in the title bar of Isabelle/jEdit? (Isabelle2012 or Isabelle2013-2?)

Comment: From the official sources, both Nominal and Isabelle. The title bar says 2013-2. How can I check which version does it use?

Comment: I installed Nominal Isabelle by untarring to my Windows home directory.

Comment: The title bar should be valid as a check. As for "from the official sources". Could you be more specific (which url and which tar file exactly)? Otherwise it is hard for me to reproduce your exact setup.

Comment: Sorry for not being precise. [Isabelle](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/hvg/Isabelle/dist/Isabelle2013-2.exe) and [Nominal](http://www.inf.kcl.ac.uk/staff/urbanc/Publications/Nominal2-2013-2.tgz) I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** This has nothing to do with having different Isabelle versions installed at the same time. Moreover, I would consider it correct behaviour, since `atom_decl` is not defined unless you load the corresponding theory file (see below).

**Answer:** I tried to reproduce the same situation (on my linux machine). Thus I downloaded
[Isabelle2013-2](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2013-2_linux.tar.gz) and [Nominal2](http://www.inf.kcl.ac.uk/staff/urbanc/Publications/Nominal2-2013-2.tgz) and *installed* (i.e., unpacked the `tar`-files) it into the local directory `~/tmp/`.

Then, imitating starting *Isabelle/jEdit* by clicking on an icon in windows, I started it via

```
$ ~/tmp/Isabelle2013-2/Isabelle2013-2
```

getting an empty buffer (`Scratch.thy`). Then I opened

```
~/tmp/Nominal2-Isabelle2013-1/Nominal/Ex/Lambda.thy
```

via *File -> Open ...*. (General note: shouldn't the directory be renamed to `Nominal2-Isabelle2013-2`?)

At this point I get a popup asking about *Auto loading of required files*. As long as I do not "answer" this popup (or close it by answering with *No*), I get exactly the error message you describe above, i.e.,

```
Outer syntax error: command expected,
but identifier atom_decl was found
```

If I answer with *Yes*, all required theories are loaded and thus the command `atom_decl` will be defined and everything is fine.

`atom_decl` is defined in `nominal_atoms.ML` which is used by `Nominal2_Base.thy`, and thus only defined after loading this theory.

Comment: I did say yes to autoloading but Isabelle/jedit did not automatically recover from the error. Sorry I am not familiar with it. And thanks.

Comment: Of course you have to wait until the theory `Nominal2_Base.thy` is actually loaded (which might take some time... in the Theory panel you can monitor the progress of the loading process). But after that, the error should be gone (assuming that continuous checking is enabled).